# Adding Panoramio Photos To An OpenLayers Map

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, json

I have a pretty well integrated OpenLayers map that I want to add photos from the Panoramio API to. Unfortunately, it seems both API's are under documented on this subject. I found one great tutorial here http://www.gisandchips.org/2010/05/04/openlayers-y-panoramio/ but as I am new to all of this, could be why I cannot complete this on my own. I feel like even using this tutorial I have a lot of blank spaces in my mind and not to mention, the photos are NOT appearing on my map :-/

Here is my portion of the code that demonstrates my use of that tutorial and what I have attempted so far:

```
var url = "http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php";
                var parameters = {
                   order:'popularity',
                   set:'full',
                   from:0,
                   to:20,
                   minx: 84.05,
                   miny: 31.36,
                   maxx: 91.89,
                   maxy: 32.30,
                   size:'thumbnail'
                }//end parameters

                OpenLayers.loadURL(url, parameters, this, displayPhotos);

                function displayPhotos(response) {
                    var json = new OpenLayers.Format.JSON();
                    var panoramio = json.read(response.responseText);
                    var features = new Array(panoramio.photos.length);

                    for (var i = 0; i < panoramio.photos.length; i++)
                    {
                        var upload_date = panoramio.photos[i].upload_date;
                        var owner_name = panoramio.photos[i].owner_name;
                        var photo_id = panoramio.photos[i].photo_id;
                        var longitude =panoramio.photos[i].longitude;
                        var latitude = panoramio.photos[i].latitude;
                        var pheight = panoramio.photos[i].height;
                        var pwidth = panoramio.photos[i].width;
                        var photo_title = panoramio.photos[i].photo_title;
                        var owner_url = panoramio.photos[i].owner_url;
                        var owner_id = panoramio.photos[i].owner_id;
                        var photo_file_url = panoramio.photos[i].photo_file_url;
                        var photo_url = panoramio.photos[i].photo_url;


                        var fpoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(longitude,latitude);

                        var attributes = {
                               'upload_date' : upload_date,
                               'owner_name':owner_name,
                               'photo_id':photo_id,
                               'longitude':longitude,
                               'latitude':latitude,
                               'pheight':pheight,
                               'pwidth':pwidth,
                               'pheight':pheight,
                               'photo_title':photo_title,
                               'owner_url':owner_url,
                               'owner_id':owner_id,
                               'photo_file_url':photo_file_url,
                               'photo_url':photo_url
                        }//end attributes

                        features[i] = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(fpoint,attributes);

                    }//end for

                    var panoramio_style2 = new OpenLayers.StyleMap(OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults({
                        pointRadius: 7,
                        fillColor: "red",
                        fillOpacity: 1,
                        strokeColor: "black",
                        externalGraphic: "panoramio-marker.png"
                    }, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]));

                    var vectorPano = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Panoramio Photos", {
                           styleMap: panoramio_style2
                    });

                    vectorPano.addFeatures(features);
                    map.addLayer(vectorPano);

                }//end displayPhotos
```

In my mind this code should work perfectly. Giving me a result of some Panoramio thumbnails on my slippy map. Unfortunately it seems that the layer is there, but blank..When I look at the response text in Firebug I can see that the JSON is returned with attributes of photos from Panoramio, in the location I have specified (Tibet). I appreciate your help and time to consider my issues.

Comment: do you have a live link? it is easier to debug.
    <script src="../../js/OpenLayers-2.8/lib/OpenLayers.js"> need full urls if not copied to your local drive.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a public live link :(, apologies for that one.  My Libraries are definitely included properly, as I can see them loaded in FireBug...

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you missing the key part of adding the image paths as your external graphics?

```
externalGraphic: "panoramio-marker.png"
```

should be a dynamic variable (of the image URL) for each image:

```
externalGraphic: "${photo_file_url}"
```

Also copy and paste your code into http://www.jslint.com/ as there are a couple of minor syntax fixes to check.